# Dynamic images ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I must add X images to the view. Each image on click should show own input below on click.

I am getting list of images into my model. In the foreach loop I can add them dynamicly but how is it possible to make onclick function original for each one, so each input will separated for each image.

```
@foreach (var image in Model.Image)
{
    <div class="col-md-2" style="cursor: pointer">
        <img src="@Url.Content(image)" alt="image" />
        <input type="text" class="form-control" style="visibility: collapse"/>
    </div>
}
```

Comment: You need javascript/jquery to handle the `.click()` event - e.g. `$('img').click(function() { $(this).next('input').show() });` - but would be better to give the elements class names and use them for the selectors.

Comment: Sure but how do I add original names for pair image/input?

Comment: What do you mean _add original names_ - why do you want to add names?

Comment: I mean original image id so function knows which one was clicked

Comment: You don't need to - `$(this).next('input')` gets the next textbox associated with the image you clicked (and if you want to refer to the images, its just `$(this)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a JavaScript function that takes a parameter, such as the clicked image element, to indicate which image was clicked and take appropriate action:

```
<img src="@Url.Content(image)" alt="image" onclick="processImage(this)" />
```

The keyword `this` is a reference to the element causing the event to trigger - in this case, an image element that's been clicked.

Comment: And to show the input is? See @ Stephen Muecke first comment.